# How to display all letters in a string except the first

Tags: python, string, input

I want to display an input() string and want to display it so it prints all the letters of the string except the first letter.

```py
string1 = input("enter first string")
string2 = input("enter second string")
print(string1[1] + (string2 - [0]))
```

I expected it to display as (for examples if string1 was pizza and string 2 was a salad) "palad"

Comment: `string1[0] + string2[1:]`

Comment: durable: `string1[:1] + string2[1:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substring. like this:

```
string1 = input("enter first string")
string2 = input("enter second string")

print(string1[0] + string2[1:])
```

string2[1:] means: substring from character 2 till the end.

Comment: you can change `string1[0]` to `string1[:1]` incase some one enters empty string.